# Error messages not appearing while Parsley.js is called in a form living inside a jQuery UI dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsley.js

I have a form living inside q jQuery UI modal and Parsley.js is not working properly since the validation messages aren't being displayed on the UI.

This is the code I've been playing with:

```
$(function() {
  $('#order_push').click(function() {
    $('#add_contact').dialog('open');
  });

  $('#add_contact').dialog({
    title: "Add Contact",
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    width: 600,
    height: 300,
    buttons: {
      'Create': function() {
        var $form = $('#contact_frm').parsley();

        if ($form.isValid()) {
          alert('valid');
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

And [here is](https://jsfiddle.net/reynierpm/r9ktyeeg/) a full example of the HTML and the JS working together. If you play a little bit with this Fiddle by leaving the fields empty you'll see how messages are not displayed. At least I would like my field to be marked in red if it's invalid or green if it's valid. Something like [this](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples/simple.html)

Did I miss something here?

Comment: Thanks for providing a working example!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calling `isValid`. The documentation states (in bold!):

> isValid: Does not affect UI nor fires events.

You want to call `validate({force: true})` (or `whenValidate` if doing async validation)

Comment: That makes it to work see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/reynierpm/r9ktyeeg/1/) but how do I achieve the nice color on the inputs valid or invalid?

Comment: I've made another example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/reynierpm/r9ktyeeg/2/) notice how the fields aren't valid however I can not get the input colored, what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Running on [Marc-André](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8279/marc-andr%C3%A9-lafortune)'s answer, which should be the one accepted, since it addresses the major issue...

About the *second question* in comments:

Just add this, which targets Parsley error message elements:

```
if($form.on('form:error')){
  $(".parsley-errors-list").prev().addClass("error");
}
```

And this CSS:

```
.error{
  border:2px solid red;
}
```

Now to remove the error class on `keyup`:

```
$("input").on("keyup",function(){
  $(this).removeClass("error");
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/7ajd33ur/)

You should take a moment to read [the Parsley documentation](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/)...
;)